# find $\int _\gamma \frac{1}{z+\frac {1}{2}}dz$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration

I'm asked to find $$\int _\gamma \frac{1}{z+\frac {1}{2}}$$ where $\gamma (t)=e^{it}, 0\leq t\leq  2\pi$.

To do this I deal with two different logarithms, one without the negative imaginary axis which I call $\log _1$ and another without the positive imaginary axis, $\log _2$.

Then $$\int _\gamma \frac{1}{z+\frac {1}{2}}=\log _1(z+\frac {1}{2})\bigg|^{z=-1}_{z=1}+\log _2(z+\frac {1}{2})\bigg|^{z=1}_{z=-1}=\\
(\log _1(-\frac {1}{2})-\log _1(\frac{3}{2}))+(\log _2(\frac {3}{2})-\log _2(-\frac{1}{2}))$$

now

- $\log _1(-\frac {1}{2})=\log (\frac{1}{2})+i\pi$
- $\log _1(\frac {3}{2})=\log (\frac{3}{2})+0$
- $\log _2(\frac {3}{2})=\log (\frac{3}{2})+\color{green}{2i\pi}$, maybe $0$ instead of green??
- $\log _2(-\frac {1}{2})=\log (\frac{1}{2})+i\pi $

so if green is right the integral is $2\pi i$ if instead of green it is $0$ the integral is $0$.

I think green is right.

can you please tell me the right answer?

Comment: You can consider $I(w) = \int_\gamma \dfrac{dz}{z-w}$. $I(0)$ is straightforward to evaluate, $I$ is holomorphic in the unit disk, and $I'(w) = \int_\gamma \dfrac{dz}{(z-w)^2} = ?$

Comment: What are you doing $\;\log_2(-3/2)\;$ instead of $\;\log_2(3/2)\;$ ??

Comment: @DonAntonio it was a typo, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your $\;\log_2(3/2)\;$ is wrong, imo:

$$\log_1\left(-\frac12\right)-\log_1\frac32+\log_2\left(\frac32\right)-\log_2\left(-\frac12\right)=$$

$$=\log\frac12+\pi i-\log\frac32+\log\frac32+2\pi i-\log\frac12-\pi i=2\pi i$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(z)=1$.  Using Cauchy's Integral Formula, we know that

$$
\int_\gamma\frac{f(z)}{z+\frac{1}{2}}dz=2\pi i\cdot f\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)=2\pi i
$$

Comment: I can't be sure but I'm almost sure the OP hasn't yet covered that,  otherwise he wouldn't be asking this question...

Comment: Sorry, but if I see "Complex-Analysis" and "Contour-Integration", there is no other way.  I see your point though.

Comment: "there is no other way"? Of course there is, though it is more cumbersome and long.

Comment: I meant it in a practical way meaning that most other ways are longer and this makes the most sense based on the tags.

Comment: I appreciate this answer, I actually know about cauchy integral formula now, but I didnt before.

Comment: @antifb Not a problem.  I just assumed that you forgot about one of the theorems you had learned or just didn't know how to apply it.  The great thing about math is that there are always different ways to solve every problem.  Glad to know I could help!